# jquery-ui sortable wrong position of the dragged item after using a shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, shadowbox

I've a strange behavior when using jquery-ui sortable.

I am using it for sorting some formsets. It works ok. However if I open and close a [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com) popup, then the sortable doesn't work properly anymore.

I don't see anymore the dragged item because of a wrong position. I've logged the dragged item position in the `over` event and see that the top position is not correct. It seems to me that the original event offset is missing.

Any idea, how to fix this issue?

Comment: js errors? library conflicts ?

Comment: maybe shadowbox uses same class/id names or whole tags overwriting some style

Comment: no specific js error. I am checking lib conflicts... 2 versions of jquery are used and i try to move everything to 1.9